# Вырезать А,В оставить Б - Нужна функция или выражение PHP

Tags: php

Есть следующий *trash* в котором нужно убить все полностью учитывая даже `<![CDATA[` и на выходе получить только  - **Текст который нужно получить в чистом виде**

Короче говоря очистить все до и после! Надеюсь суть ясна)

```
<trash>
  Много разных символов, html и т.д.
</trash>
<![CDATA[
  Текст который нужно получить в чистом виде.
]]>
<trash>
  Много разных символов, html и т.д.
</trash>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function getBetween($s1, $s2, $str){
    $s = strpos($str, $s1) + strlen($s1);
    $e = strpos($str, $s2);
    return substr($str, $s, $e-$s);
}
$data = getBetween('<![CDATA[', ']]>', $text);
```

Проблема только если таких кусков несколько. Но тогда можно regExp'ом.

Comment: Нет проблемы) там перед <![CDATA[ и после ]]> стоит еще уник который на сстранице один! Спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

$pattern = "/(<trash>[^>]+>)(s+)(<![CDATA[)([^\n]+)(s+]]>)s+(<trash>[^>]+>)/gm";

$replacement = "$4";

echo preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $string);